# How to print alphabets A to Z in oracle using ascii values?

Tags: sql, oracle

Like:

A

B

C

D

E

F

G

H

I

J

K

L

M

N

O

P

Q

R

S

T

U

V

W

X

Y

Z

Comment: What do you mean? Are you insulting the community?

Comment: Are you asking how to write an Oracle stored procedure to do this?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
select 'A' as letter from dual union all
select 'B' from dual union all
. . . 
select 'Z'
order by letter
```

(Where the `...` is just similar lines for the other letters).

Seems like a curious question, though.

---

DECLARE 
        a number;

BEGIN

FOR a in ascii('A') .. ascii('Z') LOOP

```
   dbms_output.put_line(chr(a));
```

END LOOP;
END;

by Sai Prasanth

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/12094 would be simpler :-) (though Oracle only).

Comment: @Ben . . . That is a very elegant solution for Oracle.  I'm more curious why the question is being asked.

Comment: I felt the need to try something slightly more standard. A [recursive CTE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/12102) will work as well, but because of DUAL and `chr()` vs. `char()` etc it still requires different things for each, as you almost definitely already know :-)

Comment: No offense but Ben's solution is not only more elegant but much closer to what the questioner asked.  As to why the OP wants this, I smell a school assignment or an interview exercise.